# Why do we need to use reference-qualified functions?

Tags: c++, c++11, reference, c++14, ref

Why do we need to use reference-qualified functions?

```
class Y {
  void h() &;
  void h() &&;
};
```

What is their feature and advantage over functions without reference-qualifiers (& or &&)?

Comment: Can you provide more context or a reference wher you got that from please? Is that the same like `void h();
  void h() const;`?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33941020/const-reference-qualified-member-function And here is a nice blog-post explaining Ref-qualifiers: https://akrzemi1.wordpress.com/2014/06/02/ref-qualifiers/  (I'm too lazy to post an answer out of this ...)